# PHP/HTML no imprime la info introducida por el formulario

Tags: php, html

Principiante.

Estoy tratando de crearuna actividad con los datos que introduzco por el formulario y con una imagen en función del "tipo" de actividad.
Anteriormente , en la parte en la que imprimo los resultados, no estaba usando la función isset(). Los resultados se mostraban pero, por defecto, al cargar la página de primeras sin rellenar el formulario me salia un warning:

> Warning: Undefined array key "titulo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAES\ACTIVIDAD UF1\index.php on line 30

Al usar la función isset(), ya no me sale el warning, y tengo entendido que es como debe ser ya que tiene que comprobar que haya un valor almacenado antes de imprimirlo. Pero ahora, relleno el formulario y no se imprimen los resultados al tratar de crear la actividad.

Dejo todo el código ya que no se si lo que estoy pasando por alto está donde trato de imprimir o es en el formulario. Espero que podáis ayudarme. Gracias!:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Creador de actividades</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>  

  <div class="container p-5 my-5 bg-primary text-white text-center">
  <h1>Creador de Actividades</h1>
  <p>Crea actividades a tu gusto.</p> 
</div>


 <div class="container p-5 my-5"> <!-- separación en dos columnas-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm pb-5 border text-body">
      <h2>Nueva actividad:</h2>
      <!-- formulario-->
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
        <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
          <label for="titulo" class="form-label">Título:</label>
          <input type="titulo" class="form-control" id="titulo" placeholder="Introduce título" name="titulo">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="fecha" class="form-label">Fecha:</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" placeholder="Introduce fecha" name="fecha">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Ciudad" class="form-label">Ciudad:</label>
          <input type="ciudad" class="form-control" id="ciudad" placeholder="Introduce ciudad" name="ciudad">
        </div>
        
      <div class="mb-3"> <!-- menu seleccion-->
          <label for="tipo" class="form-label">Tipo de actividad</label>
          <select class="form-select" id="tipo" name="tipo">
          <option>-</option>  
          <option>Cine</option>
          <option>Comida</option>
          <option>Copas</option>
          <option>Cultura</option>
          <option>Música</option>
          <option>Viajes</option>
          </select>
        </div> 

        <!-- radios-->
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="coste" value="Gratis" checked <?php if (isset($_POST["coste"]) && $_POST["coste"]=="Gratis") ;?>>Gratis
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="coste" value="De Pago" <?php if (isset($_POST["coste"]) && $_POST["coste"]=="De pago") ;?>>De pago

        <br><br>

        <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2"></label>
        <!-- submit-->
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Crear actividad" name="crearActividad">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div> 


    <!-- segunda columna, Actividad creada-->
    <div class="col-sm border text-body ">
      <h2>Actividad creada: </h2>

      <div class="card" style= "width:500px">
        <div clas= "container">
          <?php 
            if(isset($_POST["crearActividad"]) && $_POST["tipo"]!= "")
            {
              $imageName = ($_POST["tipo"]).".jpg";
              echo "<img class= \"mx-auto d-block\" width=\"400\" height=\"200\"src=\"./imagenes/". $imageName . "\"/>";
              }
          ?>
        </div>  
        
        -------------------------
    
           <!-- No consigo que imprima los valores que envio por el formulario -->

          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
              <?php   
                if( isset( ( $_Post["titulo"])))
                  { 
                    $titulo = ( $_Post["titulo"]);
                    echo $titulo;
                  }
              ?>
            </h4><br>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php
                if( isset( $_Post["fecha"]))
                {  
                echo $_POST["fecha"];
                }              
              ?></p>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php 
                if( isset( $_Post["ciudad"]))
                  {  
                  echo $_POST["ciudad"];
                  }
              ?></p>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php 
                if( isset( $_Post["tipo"]))
                  {  
                  echo $_POST["tipo"];
                  }
              ?></p>
            <p class="card-text">
              <?php 
                if( isset( $_Post["coste"]))
                  {  
                  echo $_POST["coste"];
                  }
              ?></p>        
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Me apunto!</a>
          </div>
------------------------------------------
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aparte de corregir lo del `$_POST` que te mencionan en la respuesta, este código creará varios elementos vacíos si ciertos datos no se mandan. ¿Es ese el comportamiento deseado?

Comment: Gracias, si, de momento no hace falta ponerle restricciones. Sobre este ejercicio lo iremos complicando y haciéndolo mas eficaz.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiar...

`$_Post`

...por...

`$_POST`

Los nombres de variables son case sensitive, incluyendo las superglobales como esta y otras (`$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION`...etc)

Por otro lado, te recomiendo explorar otra forma de hacer lo que intentas hacer. Por ejemplo, ver la posibilidad de implementar algo de AJAX vía jQuery, para que el action del formulario no apunte a la misma dirección.

Comment: Gracias por contestar! Era exactamente eso. Respecto a la forma alternativa, es literalmete el primer ejercicio con php que me han mandado. Entiendo que lo siguiente es aprender a hacerlo con métodos mas efectivos como el que me comentas. Igualmente, gracias!